# text amid an arrow by tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw an arrow by tikz which looks like:
-text->
as you can see, the text is amid the arrow, not above or below or something else. How could I make it?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome! `\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[->] (0,0) -- node[fill=white]{text} (2,0);
 \draw[->] (0,-1) -- node{text} (2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`?

Comment: Thank you very much! You have completely solved my problem. btw. I like your name^-^

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you looking for one of those.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (0,1) node [single arrow,draw]{text};
 \draw[->] (0,0) -- node[fill=white,sloped]{text} (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: also, I have a question that how to verticalize the letter of a text amid an arrow when it is vertical? Using sloped option can adjust the direction of text within an arrow, but the direction of letters of that text is always horizontal and rightward.  It comes to me that using vertical box, like \parbox is available, but LaTeX told me wrong. Is there any solution? Thanks!!

Comment: @Econometrica I do not fully understand what you are asking. Could you please add what you have tried to the question and perhaps also add a sketch of what you want to achieve. (You can add a `text width` to the node keys.)

Comment: I am really sorry for my wasting your time. A vertical arrow with text amid it without sloped option will look like a cross. So I want to type the text vertically not horizontally and I tried change line command \\ and vertical box \parbox but failed. Sloped option is not my concern cause it will rotate letter + or - 90 degrees. Thanks!

Comment: @Econometrica `\draw[->] (0,0) -- node[fill=white,align=center]{t\\ e\\ x\\ t} (2,0);`? (In order to use `\\ ` in a node you need to specify an alignment, such as `align=center`.)

Comment: Wow! you are a genius! Thanks!!

Comment: @Econometrica There is also the `decorations.text` library with which you can typeset text along curves and so on, and also transform each individual character. The pgfmanual has several examples.

Comment: I really appreciate you!! You really help me alot!